# React native: can't configure the header with navigationOptions

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am new to react-native. I am trying to configure header styles for my app, but it's not working

App.js

```
    import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
    import React, {useState} from 'react';
    import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
    import MealNavigator from './navigation/MealsNavigator';

    export default function App() {
    return (
    <MealNavigator />
    );
    }

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    });
```

The following js file i am using for navigation

MealsNavigator.js

```
    import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
    import { createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
    import categoriesScreen from '../screens/categoriesScreen';
    import categoryMealScreen from '../screens/categoryMealScreen';
    import mealDetailScreen from '../screens/mealDetailScreen';

    const MealNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Categories : categoriesScreen,
    CategoryMeals : categoryMealScreen,
    MealDetail : mealDetailScreen
    });

    export default createAppContainer(MealNavigator);
```

The following is the screen where i am trying to configure the header

categoriesScreen.js

```
    import React from 'react';
    import {Text,View,Button,FlatList,StyleSheet,TouchableOpacity, Platform} from 'react-native';
    import { CATEGORIES } from '../data/dummydata';

    const CategoriesScreen = props => {

    const renderGrid=(itemData) =>{
    return(
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.gridItem} onPress={() =>{props.navigation.navigate({routeName:'CategoryMeals'});}}>
            <View>
                <Text>{itemData.item.title}</Text>
            </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
    };

    return(
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList 
            data={CATEGORIES} renderItem={renderGrid} numColumns={2} />
    </View>
    );
    }
    CategoriesScreen.defaultNavigationOptions  = ({ navigation }) =>({
    title:'Meal Categories',
    headerTitleStyle: {
     textAlign: "left",
     fontSize: 24
    },
    });

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
    flex:1,
    justifyContent:'center',
    alignItems:'center'
    },
    gridItem:{
    flexGrow:1,
    padding: 20,
    margin: 15,
    height: 150,
    }
    });

    export default CategoriesScreen;
```

The following is the dummy data i am using

dummydata.js

```
    import Category from '../models/category';

    export const CATEGORIES = [
    new Category('c1','Indian','#f5428d'),  
    new Category('c2','Chinese','#f54242'),
    new Category('c3','Thai','#f5a442'),
    new Category('c4','Malaysian','#f5d142'),
    new Category('c5','Arabian','#368dff'),
    new Category('c6','South Indian','#41d95d'),
    new Category('c7','Kerala','#9eecff'),
    new Category('c8','Bengali','#b9ffb0'),
    new Category('c9','Mexican','#ffc7ff'),
    new Category('c10','Italian','#47fced'),  
    ];
```

Following is category class file

category.js

```
    class Category{
    constructor(id,title,color){
    this.id = id;
    this.title = title;
    this.color = color;
    }
    };
    export default Category;
```

Everything else is working, just the header configuration is not working.I am using react navigation version 4

Comment: can you upload your project to the expo?

Comment: headerTitleStyle not work?

Comment: Do you have implemented navigation stacks? because i don't think component gives defaultNavigationOptions

Comment: @Surva.D we can access navigationOptions of screen component not defaultNavigationOptions for setup configuration of the header also this totally depends which version of react navigation we are using if using with version 4 than it will works other wise it will managed by its props in version 5 of react navigation

Answer (score 0):

you can cofigure header using navigation.setOptions like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Text,View,Button,FlatList,StyleSheet,TouchableOpacity, Platform} from 'react-native';
import { CATEGORIES } from '../data/dummydata';

const CategoriesScreen = props => {

React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
     props.navigation.setOptions({ 
        headerTitle: 'Meal Categories',
        headerTitleStyle: {
            textAlign: "left",
            fontSize: 24
        },
     });
 },

const renderGrid=(itemData) =>{
return(
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.gridItem} onPress={() =>{props.navigation.navigate({routeName:'CategoryMeals'});}}>
        <View>
            <Text>{itemData.item.title}</Text>
        </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
)
};

return(
<View style={styles.container}>
    <FlatList 
        data={CATEGORIES} renderItem={renderGrid} numColumns={2} />
</View>
);
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container:{
flex:1,
justifyContent:'center',
alignItems:'center'
},
gridItem:{
flexGrow:1,
padding: 20,
margin: 15,
height: 150,
}
});

export default CategoriesScreen;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a different solution to my problem. I used defaultNavigationOptions in my navigation file.

MealsNavigator.js

```
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import categoriesScreen from '../screens/categoriesScreen';
import categoryMealScreen from '../screens/categoryMealScreen';
import mealDetailScreen from '../screens/mealDetailScreen';
import {Platform} from 'react-native';
import colors from '../constants/colors';

const MealNavigator = createStackNavigator({
Categories : {
    screen : categoriesScreen,
    navigationOptions : {
        headerTitle:'Meal Categories',    
    }
},
CategoryMeals : {
    screen : categoryMealScreen
},
MealDetail : mealDetailScreen
},
{
defaultNavigationOptions:{
    headerTitleStyle:{
        backgroundColor:Platform.OS==='android' ? colors.primaryColor : 'white'
    },
    headerTintColor:Platform.OS==='android' ? 'white' : colors.primaryColor
}
}
);

export default createAppContainer(MealNavigator);
```

Thanks to everybody for your help.